# How much ram do different python objects use?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, ram

I want to optimize my program as it consumes a lot of ram and stores a lot of data. To decide which datatype to use I need to know how much RAM a single python objects uses. How can I determine those sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`sys.getsizeof()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof).

If you want the size of a container pluss all of its content, then the doc even has a [link to a recipe](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504/) to do that.